# debugger wont show the pointed variable

Tags: c++, pointers, debugging, gdb, clion

I am debugging a code and there are 2 issues.

1. the debugger showed me the inner fields of each pointer, but suddenly it just wont, I dont know what changed or what did i click, but when i try to acsses the inner fields (like writing something into the pointed variable) it indeed shows me the correct variable, so it is saved there.
   [image]

As you can see last clearly points to something, but it doesnt show the inner variable that the pointer is pointing to.
10 minutes ago it showed them though.

2. for some reason my program runs on debugging mode but encounter some sort of an unkown infinite loop when i run it regularly. Howcome?

im using the mingw debugger (i think its called GDB) on the IDE CLion.

Comment: You added 4 tags, none of them mention which debugger you are using. Please read the question after yourself and think about whether you have given enough information for someone else to reproduce your problem and help you. Pointers do not have inner fields.

Comment: added the info, thanks.

Comment: "but it doesnt show the inner variable that the pointer is pointing to" Typically no ide shows by default the target where a pointer points to. There should be some context menu which let you show the pointer target. In ddd you have "Display *x" by right mouse key. Sorry, I don't use Clion. But should be something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea about the first part of the question, but for the second part:

> for some reason my program runs on debugging mode but encounter some sort of an unkown infinite loop when i run it regularly. Howcome?

This is *very* common.

In 99.999% of instances this happens because your program exercises undefined behavior of some sort, such as using unitialized data, accessing array out of bounds, accessing memory after it has been deallocated, etc. etc.

In the remaining 0.001% of the cases it's due to a compiler bug.

On non-Widows OSes there are tools which help find such problems quickly, such as Address and Memory Sanitizers. Looks like Address Sanitizer is also [available](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/addresssanitizer-asan-for-windows-with-msvc/) on Windows, but only under MSVC.

**Update:**

> what can i usually do in order to find those memory bugs that the debugger wont pickup on?

The usual techniques are:

- Leave no variable uninitialized.
- Add `assert()`ions to verify that indices are in bounds, etc.
- Have a very clear model of what dynamically allocated memory is owned by which object, so it's clear that no memory is accessed after it has been deleted, etc.

> if my code is lets say 1500 lines long,

That is a *very small* program. Learning [how to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) such programs will serve you well.

Comment: so what can i usually do in order to find those memory bugs that the debugger wont pickup on? if my code is lets say 1500 lines long, how can I usually pinpoint the error which makes my program run to get a wierd exit code (or sometimes be all together stuck)

Comment: @Shalevrissin Another thing you can try is to check if the bug is reproducible both in Debug and Release mode. If one of them seems to work (which is quite a common case) you can successively move subsequent compilation units to e.g. to Release mode (or viceversa) and reproduce. If you find defective .cpp file  you make a copy and act identically with particular functions. Once I narrowed down this way a sneaky bug with undefined behavior. I call it boldly a *"selective optimization switching"* :)